# How to get all pull requests using bitbucket api?

Tags: git, api, bitbucket

How to get all unread pull requests from anybody to any my repositories using bitbucket api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use API 2.0 instead API 1.0. It works fine:

```
https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/YOUR_NAME/REPO_NAME/pullrequests
```

Comment: Looks above API URL will not work. you have to use below one. https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/repositories/YOUR_NAME/REPO_NAME/pullrequests It's working fine for me with cased auth info.